# Give an example of a sequence in $l^{\infty}$ which cannot be generated by the linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Give an example of a sequence in $l^{\infty}$ which cannot be
>   generated by the linear operator
>   $$A\colon (C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty})\to l^{\infty}([0,1]); Af \mapsto
>  \{f(2^{-k})\}_{k\geq 1}.$$

I think that I need to find a sequence which is bounded (therefore an element of $l^{\infty}$), which cannot be generated due to the fact that $f$ is continuous.

Which sequence could I give that can not be generated? Would it be something where you take an arbitrarily large $N$ say and let $e_N=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$?

Comment: Your logic is getting to the right idea:  You want a bounded sequence without a limit.

Comment: Harmonic series? That was my original thought

Comment: The (partial sums of the ) harmonic series are unbounded.

Comment: The supremum of the harmonic series is 1 though. How about a series which consists of alternating 1's and 0's? (1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,...) then it's an element of $l^{\infty}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the supremum of a series.  Yes, the *sequence* which consists of alternating 1s and 0s should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For any continous function $f$, one can define the following map

$$ \Phi_f\colon l^\infty([0,1]) \to l^\infty([0,1]); \{s_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N} \mapsto \{f(s_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}. $$
In fact, $\Phi_f$ will map convergent sequences to convergent sequences.

Given that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac12^n = 0$, it follows that $\Phi_f(\{\frac12^n\}) = Af$ is also convergent.

There are of course many non convergent sequences in $l^\infty([0,1])$, so $A$ certainly cannot be surjective.